# Simple Login on Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

I'm having real trouble creating a simple login form within Bootstrap. I've read through most of the googled results and directly copied some code but i cannot get the script to run/trigger

My DB connection is working (have tested via echo) 
My PHP is

```
                <?php  //Start the Session
                session_start();
                echo log in script has run
                 require('connect.php');
                //3. If the form is submitted or not.
                //3.1 If the form is submitted
                if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
                //3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                //3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `userinfo` WHERE Email='$username' and Password='$password'";

                $result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
                echo $result
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                //3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
                if ($count == 1){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                }else{
                //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
                echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
                }
                }
                //3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
                if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
                $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                echo "Hello " . $username . "";
                echo "This is the Members Area";

                }else{
                //3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
                }
                ?>
```

and then my HTML for the form (which is standard bootstrap template is

```
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitButton" >Sign in</button>
                      </form>
                    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
                  </div>
                </nav>
```

However the script is not running at all. I'm aware that i may need an action command buit all that does it open up a seperate page

Comment: First of all there are few errors in your code like Line no3 and there is a semi colon missing on line no 15

Comment: Kindly correct those errors first and then post the screen shot of the error that you are getting

Comment: Pavan,I have corrected those errors int he code but the form isn;t doing anything.
The code should echo a greeting message, as a basic test of my script,  once a user is logged in, i am typing details in that i know are good but i get no changes to the page.

Comment: u need to provide the code from the form

Comment: The form code is the second code block in my question

Comment: What API are you using for `connect.php` and what is the connection variable for it, `$con`, `$connection`, other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

This line:

```
echo log in script has run
```

Needs to read as (missing quotes and semi-colon)

```
echo "log in script has run";
```

Then there's a missing semi-colon for `echo $result` which *technically*, should read as
`echo $result;`

However, you should remove that line, because it will throw the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in...

Then, you're not connecting to your DB with your query.

Since you didn't mention what variable you're using to connect with, I used `$con` as an example.

This line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

should read as, and using the DB connection variable as the first parameter:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

**Sidenote:** Make sure that your connection API is `mysqli_` and not `mysql_` or PDO-based. Those APIs do not intermix with each other.

If that is your actual code, where it contains spaces before your opening `<?php` tag; remove them.

In using sessions, that would count as output before header.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors and would have signaled a parse error to start with.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

It is recommended to use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, in regards to SQL injection,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Footnotes:

Since your code seems to run on the same page, I suggest you also add a conditional statement to check if the submit button was also clicked:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submitButton']) 
    && isset($_POST['username']) 
    && isset($_POST['password']) ){
```

If by adding that and it doesn't work, try changing your `<button>` to an `<input>`

I.e.:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submitButton" value="Sign in">
```

> *I'm aware that i may need an action command*

If your entire code is inside the same page and an action is omitted from `<form>`, it defaults to self, which is equivalent to doing `<form action="" method="post">`.

If your form and PHP/MySQL are not part of your form and is in a different page, then you would need to specify its action to a file `<form action="handler.php" method="post">`

---

**Edit:**

Connecting to a DB using the `mysqli_` functions example:

As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

```
<?php
//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 

     or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

- Replace/use `$link` respectively or change accordingly.

while making sure you've chosen the correct table and database.

Comment: Some really good advice there and i had missed the connection statement within my code. 
I've now made those changes but i'm still not getting any echo results (on valid or invalid detailed) amd i'm not getting any on screen or console errors. Do i need to connect the form to the php in some way?

Comment: @Brad Are you running your entire code from within the same file?

Comment: @Brad Also, you should remove `echo $result;` as I edited in my answer that it will throw `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in...` - I've tested your code and got correct results. Plus, you may have a cached session, so you'd need to destroy or unset it.

Comment: I have removed all cookies and done a reboot just to be sure. Removed the result line as you suggested but the page still does nothing. 
I have tried mysql & mysqli commands just in case. Is there a basic way i can test if my php is even running?

Comment: @Brad As I said Brad. I tested your code with no issues, after using what I posted in my answer, being the changes needed to be made. If your DB connection is using `mysql_` functions or the PDO API, then that won't work, because those functions do not intermix with each other; it should all be `mysqli_` with your posted code and passing DB connection to the query. You also didn't answer my question about: if you're running your entire code from within the same file, or seperate files.

Comment: This isnt the first time i have had trouble with a basic MYSQL/php command but i've always managed to get them working before

Comment: @Brad Well, your query failed then. Check to see if any of your columns contain spaces or the lengths are long enough.

Comment: I am running all but my connection from within the same file. I have set the commands back to MySQLi

Comment: @Brad I've edited my comment just above, about spaces in your rows, or the lengths not being long enough, or having the right column types. `require('connect.php');` - `connect.php` should be in the same folder and you could try `include 'connect.php';` instead. Make sure you've chosen the right table and DB.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I've just double checked my connect.php and it now has a table fail so i'm going to fiddle with that

Comment: @Brad You're welcome. Once you've gotten a good connection and the right table, and have used my answer and gotten results, you can then mark the question as solved. *Cheers* I added an example below in my answer near the end, under **Edit.**